# Get objects involved in Java stacktrace

Tags: java, stack-trace, callstack

I can retreive the current stacktrace using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` but this gives me only the classes involved in the call. Is it possible to retreive the object instances involved in the call trace? Maybe some kind of library which allows me to retreive the objects from the heap?

I have a problem which requires me to trace back to a Spring bean which indirectly created the object where i'm requesting the stack trace.

**UPDATE**
If there's no builtin tool for this in Java i'm searching for an embeddable library which can do this for me in runtime.

Comment: That seems to be hack the JVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very interesting idea, but, unfortunately in whole **no**, you could not, it is impossible.

<strike>**UPD:** One of the reasons why answer is "no" is that fact, that if it could be possible, then some List of references to all created objects must exist. But in this case Java GC would not work at all.</strike>

Comment: The argument doesn't hold: Java has `WeakReference` for exactly this sort of use cases.

Comment: Isn't the heap storing all the object references involved in a call? I mean the JVM has to resume the caller method once the sub-function call is complete. Is it impossible to access this part of the heap?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [housemd](https://github.com/zhongl/HouseMD). It's developed by an engineer@alibaba and safe to be used even in a production environment, e.g. taobao.com.

Its feature include:

> ```
> Display object field value
> Output invocation stack trace
> ```

Following is an example screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Seems like i was not clear enough with my question. I'm search for an embeddable library which can do the same thing for me in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Eclipse debugger in order to view the value of objects used in a particular method. Place breakpoints on the lines where you want to pause the program.