# Lookup the method caller inside the called method

Tags: java

Supose that we have this stackTrace

```
ViewField.getValue()
ExpressionEl.doSomethink()
....
HtmlInput.getValue()
```

Is it possible to get the instance of the HtmlInput whose calling thoses methods inside the ViewField.getValue() ?

Unfortunatly the stacktrace didn't contain the reference of the caling objects, so how to do it?

Comment: Why you need the instance? The exception will be here with all instances. If you need to know the state of variables just put a breakpoint.

Comment: no i need to make a relation between my ViewField and the input whose getting his value expression from it

Comment: in other words i need to identify the input, exception had no relationship with my needs

Comment: if it was possible i wouldn't ask the question, but in fact finding the instance of the caller is almost impossible

Comment: according to that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337534/get-objects-involved-in-java-stacktrace its looks impossible

Answer (score 1):

One method that is kinda ugly but will definitely work is manually passing the reference to each method call.

If you had a method

```
void foo(String a,int b,...)
```

now it would be

```
void foo(String a,int b,Object c,...)
```

and then everywhere you call it just pass a reference to **this**.