# Printing JVM stack traces with extra information from object references

Tags: debugging, jvm, profiling

I have a Java+Scala application with lazy, monadic control flow.  As a consequence, the stack traces one gets out of a debugger or profiler look like this:

```
....
at tarski.JavaScores$FlatMapState.extract(JavaScores.java:175)
at tarski.JavaScores$Extractor.force(JavaScores.java:117)
at tarski.JavaScores$FlatMapState.extract(JavaScores.java:152)
at tarski.JavaScores$Extractor.force(JavaScores.java:117)
at tarski.JavaScores$LazyPlus.force(JavaScores.java:486)
at tarski.JavaScores$FlatMapState.extract(JavaScores.java:152)
at tarski.JavaScores$Extractor.force(JavaScores.java:117)
....
```

All that stack trace says is "We're in the lazy, monadic part of the code", which is useless.  However, one of the fields of `FlatMapState` is a function object, so if I could get at the references to `FlatMapState` I could print out nice augmented stack traces showing what is really going on.  This would help debugging and profiling immensely.

**Main question**: Is there a way to get at the references to objects in a stack trace, if necessary by interacting programmatically with a debugger or doing other environmental trickery?

Note that `StackTraceElement` contains only strings, so `getStackTrace()` is no help.  Other people have asked similar questions without answers, such as [Get objects involved in Java stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337534/get-objects-involved-in-java-stacktrace).  However, I am hoping that by giving the larger context for why I want this information (profiling), someone might have a useful idea that dodges the impossible part.

One thing I can do is maintain my own stack on the side, maintained by the FlatMapState objects as appropriate.  Unfortunately, I don't see any easy way to correlate this with the normal stack (which custom level corresponds to which normal level?), so the information would be hard to present and maintain.

Comment: NetBeans' debugger has an option to break on uncaught exceptions, letting you inspect the stack at the point of the throw (including switching to lower stack frames and inspecting their locals).  I've never tried to use it with Scala, though.

Comment: JProfiler and IntelliJ can do that too, but I'm looking for something programmatic.  I want to see a picture of the whole stack trace to get intuition for what's going on, so solutions which take minutes of human time per trace are out.