# Is there any way to find all context holders of an Activity in runtime?

Tags: android, reference, android-context

If the only way to get context of a class was "getContextOfMe()" at least I could know which objects are trying to get the context.

So, I am curious if there is a way (somehow) to become the-man-in-the-middle and detect any interest of context for a specific object.

So, as a result, I could make a function which had this line:
`Log.d("MyActivity",interestedObject+" interested in my context?!");`

(I know that I can get some information about context holders with MAT, that is why I especially added `runtime` word in the question.)

Comment: Is there any specific action you want to perform?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to be "The man in the middle" between an activity and its context because the Activity itself is the context. To be more exact, the class `Activity` is a subclass of `Context`.

What you are asking is to be able to detect when a certain activity object is being downcast to a context object, which should be impossible, and would also turn this into a java question, not an android question.

An alternative is to override all of the context methods and inserting the log message in every method, but even then according to [Get objects involved in Java stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337534/get-objects-involved-in-java-stacktrace) you will not be able to get the calling object at runtime.